# Input stream on C

Tags: c, input, stream

So I'm having a hard time understanding and getting my piece of code to work.

I have that code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    while(1){
        // Buffer containing one sample (left and right, both 16 bit).
        int16_t samples[2];
        unsigned cbBuffer=sizeof(samples);  // size in bytes of 

        // Read one sample from input
        int got=read(STDIN_FILENO, samples, cbBuffer);
        if(got<0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read from stdin failed, error=%s.", argv[0], strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }else if(got==0){
            break;   // end of file
        }else if(got!=cbBuffer){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Did not receive expected number of bytes.\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }

        // Copy one sample to output
        int done=write(STDOUT_FILENO, samples, cbBuffer);
        if(done<0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Write to stdout failed, error=%s.", argv[0], strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }else if(done!=cbBuffer){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Could not read requested number of bytes from stream.\n", argv[0]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which I call on the terminal with that:

```
./mp3_file_src.sh bn9th_m4.mp3 | ./passthrough  > /dev/null
```

I would like to modify the code so that he can take a number n and process n samples (so I get `samples[2*n]` in my code). If no arguments is given to the executable then use a default value.

If I understand correctly, I can verify if an argument is given if `argc>2` ? But then I can't seem to understand how I can get that argument and pass it through in my code.

Any idea?

Comment: Well basically you get the number of arguments from argc variable and the value of arguments from argv array. You would have to loop through the argv array till argc times.

Answer (score 1):

Just access it through `argv[1]`. If it's a numeric argument, you'll need to convert it from a string into a number, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int default_opt = 5, option = 0;

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        printf("You didn't supply an argument, using default.\n");
        option = default_opt;
    } else {
        char * endptr;
        option = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
        if ( *endptr ) {
            printf("You supplied an invalid argument, exiting.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Option set to %d.\n", option);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./arg
You didn't supply an argument, using default.
Option set to 5.
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./arg 7
Option set to 7.
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./arg whut
You supplied an invalid argument, exiting.
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```

Comment: That's great thanks. So I use, argv to get the string. But he doesn't care about ./mp3_file_src.sh bn9th_m4.mp3 as an argument, because of the |, right ? Arguments are only given after the exe call ? Let's say for example I wan't to merge two input streams, then I have to put them after the exe right.

Comment: What you're talking about is a shell issue, not a programming issue. When you pipe your output from `mp3_file_src.sh` to `passthrough`, `passthrough` doesn't know anything about `mp3_file_src.sh` - your shell is just piping the standard output of `mp3_file_src.sh` to the standard input of `passthrough`. The shell invokes `passthrough` with whatever arguments you specify for `passthrough`, which in every shell I know you do by specifying them immediately after the command, or filename.

Answer (score 0):

`argc` is the number of elements in `argv`, which contains the arguments given to your program. The first element of `argv` (`argv[0]`) is the executable-name so `argc` is always at least 1. So you check if `argc > 2` to see if any arguments were given.

Note that the arguments are always strings, so to extract a number from them you need to use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) or similar.